# Getting a boolean value from xmlhttp.responseText

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have my code like this for geetting the value of the variable isItemLocked.

```
 function authorItem(itemNumber){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                    {
                      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    }else{
                        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    url ="Some URL";
                    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
                    xmlhttp.send(null);
                    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                        var isItemLocked = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        if(isItemLocked){
                            alert('Item has been Closed.Click OK to go to Search Page');
                            window.location = "SOME OTHER URL";
                        }else{
                            var url ="SOME OTHE URL 1";
                            location.href = url;    
                        }
                }
            }
 }
```

A returnning boolean value true for isItemLocked.But each time I am going to SOME OTHER URL.Any solutions?

Comment: What _exactly_ is returned in `xmlhttp.responseText`? Is is a string saying `true/false`? A number?

Comment: This looks unfortunately like W3School's race condition prone XHR code. You need to work to eliminate the globals from it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`xmlhttp.responseText` doesn't return a boolean, it returns a string and `"false"` is `true`.

Perform a string comparison.

```
if (isItemLocked === 'true') {
    // Do one thing
} else if (isItemLocked === 'false') {
    // Do a different thing
} else {
    // You have an unexpected response from the server and should handle the error
}
```

Comment: Modified my code like function authorItem(itemNumber){ if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); }else{ xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); } url ="SOME URL"; xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true); xmlhttp.send(null); xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) { var isItemLocked = xmlhttp.responseText.toString(); if(isItemLocked == 'Y'){ alert('Item has been Closed.Click OK to go to Search Page'); window.location = "SOME URL 1"; }else{ var url ="SOME OTHER URL"; location.href = url;
} } } } but still not workin?Am i missing anything?

Comment: Possibly white space in the data.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var isItemLocked = xmlhttp.responseText.toString().toLowerCase() == "true";
```

The `responseText` is coming back as a string so you need to check if it is equal to the string "true"