# AJAX request returning response text of 'false' instead of desired response text

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have a browserside javascript file that's supposed to be asking the serverside php file for a string with an ajax request. The php file seems to have the correct string, but for some reason the ajax request is returning the string 'false'.
This is the php file, named test.php:

```
    <?php
$dir = "site/uploads";
$a = scandir($dir);
$b = json_encode($a);
echo $b;
?>
```

This is the js file:

```
function load(){
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.responseType = "text";
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
     console.log('test' + xmlhttp.responseText);
     console.log('test' + JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText));
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "test.php", 'false');
xmlhttp.send();

var xmlhttp2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp2.responseType = "text";
xmlhttp2.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xmlhttp2.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp2.status == 200) {
     console.log('test2' + xmlhttp2.responseText);
     console.log('test2' + JSON.parse(xmlhttp2.responseText));
  }
};
xmlhttp2.open("GET", "test2.php", 'false');
xmlhttp2.send();
}
```

when i open the website in my browser and run load(), the console reads:
testfalse
testfalse
test2false
test2false
and has no errors. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: The problem is likely in your PHP code. My guess is the directory you try to list does not exist. Scandir returns an array of filenames on success, or FALSE on failure. Try a `var_dump` of $a.

Comment: var_dump($a) returns an array of the correct strings, and var_dump($b) gives the strings as json

Comment: @phlhg can't seem to comment because i don't have enough rep. it just says just bool(false) in the preview and response tabs

Answer (score 0):

`scandir()` in the php-file is probably returning `false`, because of an error.

https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.scandir.php (Check the return values)

There are multiple possiblities for this to happen:

- The folder doesn't exist
- The path is incorrect (Try using absolute paths)
- The folder isn't accessible, because of missing permissions

Comment: the return value of scandir() seems fine when i test it in my IDE.
i gave everyone full RWX permissions for the php files, uploads files, etc. and nothing changed. :/

Comment: Have you checked the network tab in the developer tools of your browser?

Comment: seems like the connection is fine, preview and response both just say 'false'

Comment: What's the output in the network tab if you replace ```echo  $b``` with ```echo  var_dump($a)``` in test.php?

Comment: it just says just bool(false) in the preview and response tabs

Comment: it just says just bool(false) in the preview and response tabs.

Comment: I'm returning `json_encode(false)` on purpose, but when I test for it `if (!!request.responseText)` it says it's not `false` – but when I do `console.log(request.responseText)` it is `false`! What's up with that?

Comment: Never mind, I found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4154690/3763235)!